# why is componentWillReceiveProps deprecated?

Tags: reactjs

I read through https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change . I am still not able to understand why did they have to deprecate componentWillReceiveProps.
 What was the harm in making an ajax call inside componentWillReceiveProps? Once ajax call returns the value , I update the state thereby rerendering the component.

Comment: I don't think getDerivedStateFromProps is asynchronous.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13541

Answer (score 46):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is a **synchronous** hook. Calling asynchronous function like data fetching inside this hook will need to render in between when the new props are set and when data has finished loading.

But the `getDerivedStateFromProps` is an **asynchronous** hook won't require any additional render. Thus, `componentWillReceiveProps` is being deprecated in favor of the following reason:

1. Use getDerivedStateFromProps
2. Or, use componentDidUpdate

Which won't give you unnecessary renders. Note that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is used only in rare case though. So, I suggest you to use `componentDidUpdate` hook as far as possible.

---

The similar things happen when comparing componentWillMount and componentDidMount. Use componentDidMount whenever you need operate async operation and forget componentWillMount at all condition. More explanation about componentDidMount is here in my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092495/2138752).

Comment: Could you pls explain what's a 'synchronous hook'? and why do you favour componentDidUpdate over componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Comment: My confusion ends here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that if the `componentWillReceiveProps()` method is being invoked then some properties of the component has been changed and that component should be informed and potentially re-rendered again.

Having ajax call inside of the `componentWillReceiveProps()` might break that flow.

My gut feeling is that we are gently guided to make ajax calls outside of the components and pass all the results of those ajax calls through properties. It makes your components very clean and testable.