# How to access and smoothly transition methods and this.state in componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {   

     if (
        **this.state.clicked** &&
        this.props.something &&
        nextProps.addSubtract
      ) {
          this.setState({ valid: nextProps.isValid });
        }


        if (!this.props.someItems) {
           this.setState({ products: nextProps.propsValues});
        }

        if (nextProps.valueOfProps && **this.methodOnClass**) {
            ..........
            ..........
        }
    }
```

The code above is similar to a new project I'm working on and I have encountered a road-block. Since **componentWillReceiveProps** is deprecated and I need to replace a lot of code inside it with **this.method** and **this.state** , is there a way to access these in **getDerivedStateFromProps** without moving a lot of logic in other lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not a replacement of `componentWillReceiveProps`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980977/why-is-componentwillreceiveprops-deprecated/51981144#51981144) for more detail.

To return the state by using `getDerivedStateFromProps`, you simply return an object.

Example:

```
return {
  myState: 'updated state'
}
```

If no condition match, simply return null:

```
return null
```

Similar to setState example:

```
setState({myState: 'updated state'})
```