# Animating out a React component before unmounting that has lost the props data it needs to display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I've got a Tooltip component that shows & hides depending on whether there is text data for it or not:

```js
{this.state.tooltipText && (
  <Tooltip
    text={this.state.tooltipText} />
)}
```

If I wanted to transition this component in and out, I might instead include a boolean `on` prop and let the component manage transitioning out itself.

```js
<Tooltip
  on={this.state.tooltipText !== null}
  text={this.state.tooltipText} />
```

With this setup, though, I lose the `text` prop right when the transition out should begin. There is very clearly never a state where `on` is `false` and I still have access to the `text` prop.

Is there a good way to handle this scenario?

- Should the component keep an internal record of the previous state of `tooltipText`?
- Or is it best to use two properties to track the state of the tooltip (`tooltipOn` and `tooltipText`) and never erase `this.state.tooltipText`?

Answer (score 1):

> Should the component keep an internal record of the previous state of tooltipText?

Yes. Otherwise the parent would have to decide when the transition starts / ends, which is not his authority.

Actually `componentWillReceiveProps` is best for this as you can access the current & next props:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.text && !nextProps.text) {
    this.fadeOut();
  } else if(!this.props.text && nextProps.text) {
    this.setState({ text: nextProps.text });
    this.fadeIn();
  }
}
```

Then the parent just has:

```
 <Tooltip text={this.state.tooltipText} />
```

Comment: `componentWllReceiveProps` is being deprecated in React 17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980977/why-is-componentwillreceiveprops-deprecated

Comment: Looks like this is actually not the right way to go. As @EvanTrimboli points out, `componentWillReceiveProps` is being deprecated. Also, this solution creates a duplicate, separate `text` state for the component.

Comment: I opted to go w/ the `tooltipOn` + `toolTipText` option, and it's working well enough

Comment: @SCCOTT well `getDerivedStateFromProps` would also work, and thats not deprecated. "looks like this is actually not the right way to go", thats how I'd do it, I haven't said that this is the best solution ...