# laravel react, data need refresh after form submit

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have made a component with 2 column section . left one is form and right one show all posts from db. after submitting form new inserted data doesn't show in right section unless I refresh, can anybody help? tkx

Comment: It would be easier to provide solutions if you provided some code, the way you submit your form data and handle the response in your component would be good for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in your component and set your posts state in `componentWillReceiveProps` and automatically your component will re-render.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';

class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.posts) {
      this.setState({ posts: nextProps.posts });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.posts.map((post, index) => (
          <p>{post.title}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});

export default Post;
```

**Note: This will work if your React version is less than 17**

`componentDidUpdate` will work if you are using most latest version of react. Here is the [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980977/why-is-componentwillreceiveprops-deprecated)

Comment: I use useEffect(), data are show  in console after submit but not in page unless I refresh the page.

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi is this your own custom function `useEffect()`? Please update your answer and provide some code for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, after storing into db, make request from db/api get all relevant records  and show all the lists, and update state of component.